# How to remove unwanted space in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, description

[image]
[image]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\begin{document}

\section{Formula}   
\subsection{Time-varying Coefficients}
    \begin{frame}{Time-varying Coefficients}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    Used to get the degree of ERPT:\\
    $$ERPT = \alert<2>{\beta_0} + \alert<3>{\phi_0}\alert<4>{G(s_t;\gamma,c)}$$
    \begin{description}
        \uncover<2,5>{\item [$\beta_0$] pass-through elasticity}
        \uncover<3,5>{\item [$\phi_0$] pass-through coefficient}
        \uncover<4,5>{\item [$(s_t;\gamma,c)$] logistic transition function driving the nonlinear dynamic}
        \item[]
    \end{description}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

if i remove the `\item[]` the the `\item [$(s_t;\gamma,c)$] logistic transition function driving the nonlinear dynamic` becomes left-aligned up to the border!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I see no difference with or without last `\item[]`. By the way, take a look at [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/990#990)

Answer (score 3):

you do not need the `\uncover`, you have already set `transparent` option. Use `\item<...>` instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\begin{document}

\section{Formula}   
\subsection{Time-varying Coefficients}
    \begin{frame}{Time-varying Coefficients}
        \setbeamercovered{transparent}
        Used to get the degree of ERPT:\\
        \[ERPT = \alert<2>{\beta_0} + \alert<3>{\phi_0}\alert<4>{G(s_t;\gamma,c)}\]
        \begin{description}
            \item<2,5>[$\beta_0$] pass-through elasticity
            \item<3,5> [$\phi_0$] pass-through coefficient
            \item<4-> [$(s_t;\gamma,c)$] logistic transition function driving the nonlinear dynamic
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```